# How to save data in my settings menu in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, settings

I was wondering how to save data locally in Flutter. I am creating a Settings menu in my app, and I have a draft made of that UI, but I want to save the user's preferences when they close that menu, but I have no idea how to accomplish that.

Do you know some tutorial to do so? I have searched in Youtube, but I have no idea how to search for it. I have only found UI tutorials and I don't want that.

A picture of my UI is (I want to save that boolean option).

[image]

I would appreciate any help you could give to me!

Answer (score 6):

You should use `shared_preferences` package. It's very simple and it's for non-critical data like this! Here is an example how to use it:

```
class SettingsRepository {
  final SharedPreferences preferences;

  SettingsRepositoryImpl(this.preferences);

  Future<int> getDifficulty() {
    return preferences.getInt(Keys.difficulty) ?? 1;
    // this 1 in the end is a default value
  }

  Future setDifficulty(int difficulty) {
    return preferences.setInt(Keys.difficulty, difficulty);
  }
}
```

To learn more go to https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences. I assume you want to call `preferences.setBool`

Comment: I have a question, that 'preferences' variable is saved forever with the user's selection whenever I call it? Won't it restart if I try calling it? How should I instantiate this class in my settings page to show that info in my main page? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Every time you invoke SharedPreferences constructor it returns the same thing, because it calls Shared Preferences API under the hood. You can create a class like in the answer, invoke it's constructor and save it to a variable in the main page. Then call the methods on it. You can get the initial values before building widgets in your main.dart's `run` function. Or use them in build functions but you will have to use FutureBuilder I guess. The way you use it depends on what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

You can save your boolean option using [shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences).

```
  Future<Null> saveOption(bool isSelected) async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('option', isSelected);
   
  }
```

Then you can get the option from there.

```
  Future<bool> getOption() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getBool('option');
   
  }
```

You can read more from [here](https://medium.com/@lawrey/flutter-local-storage-ac2eaf1194be).

Comment: Those functions look great, but where am I supposed to write them? Should I create another .dart file to create a new class and there write those pieces of code? In that case, are the settings saved with the option selected by the user whenever I call that class? As you can see, I don't know how to apply that correctly lol. Although, thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, you need to write another .dart file. Can you share the code you already have?